# Как добавить градиент на UIView background ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

Нужно градиент добавить как background color, чтобы элементы которые будут добавлены сверху были видны. При попытке использовать метод insertSublayer atIndex:0 вместо градиента получается тень над view. Подскажите как исправить данную проблему.

```
UIRectCorner corners = UIRectCornerTopRight | UIRectCornerBottomRight;
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.myView.bounds byRoundingCorners:corners cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(150.f, 150.f)];

CAShapeLayer *segment = [CAShapeLayer layer];
segment.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
segment.lineWidth = 1.0;
segment.path = path.CGPath;

segment.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
segment.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(30, 0);
segment.shadowOpacity = 0.75;
segment.shadowRadius = 3.0;
segment.shadowPath = segment.path;

[self.myView.layer addSublayer:segment];

CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
UIColor *firstColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
UIColor *secondColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
gradient.colors = @[(__bridge id)firstColor.CGColor, (__bridge id)secondColor.CGColor];
gradient.frame = CGPathGetBoundingBox(segment.path);

CAShapeLayer *mask = [CAShapeLayer layer];
CGAffineTransform translation = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-CGRectGetMinX(gradient.frame),
                                                                 -CGRectGetMinY(gradient.frame));
mask.path = CGPathCreateCopyByTransformingPath(segment.path,
                                               &translation);
gradient.mask = mask;

[self.myView.layer addSublayer:gradient];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// Создание градиента
    UIColor *leftColor = [UIColor redColor];
    UIColor *middleColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    UIColor *rightColor = [UIColor redColor];

    CAGradientLayer *theViewGradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    theViewGradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: (id)leftColor.CGColor, (id)middleColor.CGColor,(id)rightColor.CGColor, nil];
    theViewGradient.frame = self.view.bounds;

//Добавление градиента

[self.view.layer insertSublayer:theViewGradient atIndex:0];
```